# Edit bean data with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces

I need to change bean list data by using javascript. So:

- user presses on the command button
- command button executes the javascript mehtod(*addToList*)
- the javascript method updates the bean list(*dataList*)

***EXAMPLE CODE***

**Bean**

```
@Component("dataBean")
@Scope("session")
public class DataBean {
    List<DataModel> dataList; // THIS WILL BE EDITED

    public List<DataModel> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }

    public void setDataList(List<DataModel> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }
}
```

**Jsf**

```
<p:commandButton value="Add To List" id="btnSave" onclick="#{addToList()}"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function addToList() {
    var temp = "Opel";
    ******************
    // ADD THIS temp ITEM TO THE BEAN LIST(dataList)
    ******************  
}
```

How can I make this client to server data(bean data) transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml

call your bean with this component:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="myRemoteCommand " ...
```

Than you can use javascript function myRemoteCommand in your function addToList()

Comment: Thanky you for your response but it is about manipulating bean data from javascript. And this seems to be useful when you want to call javascript methods from bean.

Comment: @KorkiKorkig: no it **is** for calling serverside thing from the client side. Just read its documentation